# SQL query to check occurrences of multiple conditions in one column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in a SQLite DB. One contains player information, including an id, first name and surname. The second contains a list of instances where a game has been played, including the date, what type of game was played, and which player participated (i.e., several players might play the same game on the same day and so there could be multiple records with the only differences listing a different player id).

The tables look like this (apologies for formatting - I'm new):

**tbl_players**

```
| id |  firstname  |  surname  |  
+----+-------------+-----------+  
|  1 | Leto        | Atreides  |  
|  2 | Paul        | Atreides  |  
|  3 | Peter       | de Vries  |  
|  4 | Vladimir    | Harkonnen |  
|  5 | Feyd-R      | Harkonnen |  
|  6 | Duncan      | Idaho     |  
|  7 | Gurney      | Halleck   |  
|  8 | Hasimir     | Fenring   |
```

**tbl_games**

```
| id |   game   |   date    | playerid |  
+----+----------+-----------+----------+  
|  1 | Football | 3/10/2020 |        1 |  
|  2 | Tennis   | 3/10/2020 |        1 |  
|  3 | Football | 3/10/2020 |        2 |  
|  4 | Cricket  | 4/10/2020 |        3 |  
|  5 | Football | 4/10/2020 |        4 |  
|  6 | Cricket  | 4/10/2020 |        1 |  
|  7 | Cricket  | 4/10/2020 |        2 |  
|  8 | Football | 5/10/2020 |        6 |  
|  9 | Tennis   | 5/10/2020 |        7 |  
| 10 | Cricket  | 5/10/2020 |        3 |  
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

I am trying to write a SQL query that will output a list of all players with a boolean or count to tell me who has participated in three different types of sport. It would look like this:

**desired output**

```
+----------+--------------+  
| playerid | sports_played|  
+----------+--------------+  
|  1       |            3 |  
|  2       |            2 |  
|  3       |            1 |  
+----------+--------------+
```

I can do this for an individual player and game type with something along these lines:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(game)) FROM tbl_games WHERE playerid = 1
```

I am finding it difficult to work out how to get a full table with a count of game types for each player. If I remove the WHERE condition it pools the count across all players but I want to keep each player's count separate.

Will I need to do some form of full OUTER JOIN and/or a subquery? I can JOIN on playerid but that is as far as my SQL knowledge will take me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You just need a GROUP BY on playerid:

```
SELECT playerid, COUNT(DISTINCT(game)) AS CountOfSports
FROM tbl_games
GROUP BY playerid
ORDER BY playerid
```

Comment: I would suggest adding `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(game)) = 3` to address the "who has participated in three different types of sport" concern.